# What should I do if my Rails tests don't pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I want to start contributing to Rails, fixing patches, submitting my own code etc, and the Rails guide states that the tests MUST run. However, they're currently not and I'm not quite sure what to do.

I'm running Mac OS X, Ruby 1.8 and I have all the needed gems installed - what can I do?

Comment: are you getting any errors? Do you not know where or how to run the tests? Try give us a little more info and it'll help us point you in the right direction :)

Comment: Did you try running the tests before you added your feature? Be sure to always start with passing tests and run them regularly as you change the code so you can determine what change broke the tests.

Comment: Just to clarify - you downloaded edge Rails and the tests don't run successfully even before you've made any changes?

Comment: Sarah's got it - I haven't made any changes - I'm running from a clean copy of edge Rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to look is the [Rails continuous integration server](http://ci.rubyonrails.org/), which will tell you if there are any currently failing tests. It looks like the most recent edge Rails build failed, and if you checked out the code at any time between August 8th and 16th, you probably got a build with a few failures.

Comment: FWIW, that's not a common state of affairs. On the weekend of August 8th and 9th there was a Rails Bugmash in which almost 200 tickets were closed and lots of new people got their first piece of code into Rails. As a result, there was some cleanup to do, but it should be mostly complete now. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/7/28/rails-bugmash

Answer (score 0):

The failing CI tests were due to errors with SQLite2 (now removed from master) and Postgres. We fixed these, but none of these run from a normal rake test so your problems probably aren't related.

Make sure you have the latest Mocha gem installed and that you follow the directions provided by Mike Gunderloy on his afreshcup.com blog: http://afreshcup.com/2008/10/27/contributing-to-rails-step-by-step/